How to return a status code from a script executed using osascript?
In MacOS, it is possible to write command-line scripts in AppleScript using a shebang line that invokes osascript. When doing that, how can I return an exit status other than 0 or 1? If I use AppleScript's error statement with an argument number, for example like this:
#!/usr/bin/osascript

on run
    error "some message" number 3
end run

then no matter what number I use, the exit status in the shell is always 1:
# ./astest.sh
./astest.sh:15:29: execution error: some message (3)
# echo $?
1

Is there an AppleScript construct I've missed that would let me return an exit status code from the script? Failing that, is there another way (perhaps using the Foundation framework) to accomplish this?
EDIT 2024-06-28: I should have mentioned that I also tried using return, for example return 3, but this does not set the exit status in the calling shell. When using return VALUE, the VALUE you provide is printed to stdout only, and the exit status is always 0.
(To answer an anticipated comment: yes, I'm aware there are other ways to write scripts in AppleScript in combination with osascript. I'm looking for a solution that applies to this way, when using the shebang approach, not some other ways.)

It seems the options are outputting a string as your result or writing to a file... https://discussions.apple.com/thread/819796?sortBy=best

Or wrapping your osascript stuff inside a bash script that reads the string-like output of your osascript and converts it to a proper, regular bash exit status.

You can return a return value in AppleScript with return, for example return 3. See return

You can get the script's error number using NSAppleScript or NSTask, is there a particular reason for wanting to use osascript?

@Willeke Unfortunately, no, I tried that already. Whatever value you put in the return statement, the status code in the calling shell is 0. I probably should have mentioned that too. I'll edit my answer.

@red_menace Yes. Due to a combination of factors, I need it to be a script that will be executed on the command line from common utilities such as make and other scripts. In the worst case, I can accept that I can only get status codes of 0 or 1, and not any other number – that's the most essential, and it does work. However, if there's a way to produce other status codes, it would be helpful.

That is correct - osascript only returns its own exit status, not that of the script.  To get the script's error message and/or number you would need to extract that from the result.

I don't understand your requirement about being run by make and so on. Can you elaborate please? What stops you writing a bash script that runs osascript and interprets its textual output in order to exit with a non-zero exit status?
